# Onesignal vs GCM(FCM)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I use FCM in my social messaging app. Sometimes FCM messages can not be delivered from the server to client.

Is there any benefit to using OneSignal when I've got to do the full FCM setup as well in server and client sides?

I reviewed OneSignal documents this link: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/product-overview 
but I could not understand which was more useful.

Comment: if you are integrating FCM with Wordpress then one signal is a good choice as you no need to write the server side code to send the notification. one signal will handle the notification. you only need to setup the FCM and integrate the SDK

Comment: I have a social messaging app. Which one should I choose now?

Comment: If you want fewer dependencies then go with your own solution. create your own server code to push the notification. also its easy to customization purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I help work on OneSignal. Here are some reasons that OneSignal could be useful in this case.

- OneSignal provides a single API and management interface for APNS (iOS notifications) and FCM (Android notifications).
- OneSignal tracks notification click-rate for individual messages and campaigns.
- OneSignal provides an SDK that takes care of reliably displaying messages that are received, restoring messages after an app update (on Android), and making it easy to customize notification categories, sounds, LED color, and Lockscreen visibility.
- OneSignal stays up to date with any changes made to the operating system or notification APIs so you get access to the latest platform features without any additional engineering work.

Comment: FCM and APNS have these features, don't they?

Answer (score 7):

FCM has two types of messages.Notification message which deliver in most cases, and data message which doesn't sometimes. A possible solution is to set priority of data message to HIGH while sending from server side. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options