# FCM: Is data message delivery really less reliable than notification message delivery?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

#### Question

I have come across some voices stating that *FCM data message delivery is less consistent* compared to that of notification messages. Does anyone have direct experience or can point me to resources exploring the issue? Or is a notification message just a collapsible, high-priority data message that the Firebase SDK handles automatically?

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998176
- [FCM data message not received in Android when the application is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162143/fcm-data-message-not-received-in-android-when-the-application-is-in-background)
- [About FCM's notification message and data message type, which has better receiving rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896980/about-fcms-notification-message-and-data-message-type-which-has-better-receivi)

The question does not consider the case of force quitting the app. In this scenario, both types of messages will not be delivered (to my knowledge).

#### Background

I am writing a new Android SDK for a push service provider (similar to OneSignal). The SDK should handle the display of push notifications by default, optionally the client app can handle incoming pushes itself.

The actual delivery is of course done by Firebase Cloud Messaging (on devices running Play Services). So there are 2 types of messages to choose from on FCM: **data** vs **notification** messages.

As data messages are consistently handled by the registered `FirebaseMessagingService` (provided there is no `notification` key in the payload), this should be the way to go for the SDK. [[See documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)] So far, I have not been able to produce a situation in which a data message was not delivered (foreground or background).

Answer (score 0):

By setting the priority in Message, We can reflect the delivery.

You have two options for assigning delivery priority to downstream messages on Android: normal and high priority. Delivery of normal and high priority messages works like this:

**Normal priority.** This is the default priority for [data messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/message-priority#data_messages). Normal priority messages are delivered immediately when the device is not sleeping. When the device is in [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#understand_doze), delivery may be delayed to conserve battery until the device exits doze. For less time-sensitive messages, such as notifications of new email, keeping your UI in sync, or syncing app data in the background, choose normal delivery priority.

When receiving a normal priority message on Android that requests a background data sync for your app, you can schedule a task with [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to handle it when the network is available.

**High priority.** FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing FCM to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing (including very limited network access). High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications.

See *Set and manage message priority* topic in FireBase Documentation.
For More details you can prefer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/message-priority)

For *Displaying the Notification* You Can Prefer this [link](https://medium.com/@Codeible/android-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-914623716dea#Displaying%20the%20Notification:%7E:text=Displaying%20the%20Notification)

Best Of Luck In Advance.